# How to stop background processes from outputting permanently?

Tags: linux, terminal, stdout

In my newly installed Lubuntu virtual machine terminal, when I run `firefox &` firefox runs in the background, but it keeps on outputting in my terminal. I found a way to stop it from another superuser answer using the following command:

`firefox </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

However, this only works for the current terminal session. How can I stop a process from outputting to terminal **permanently**?

Answer (score 2):

Create a shell alias:

```
alias firefox='firefox </dev/null &>/dev/null &'
```

Or:

Write a shell wrapper script that will call firefox the way you already figured out.

Name your script `firefox`, make it executable and make sure it is saved in a directory that is before a directory with the original Firefox in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: your answer is specific to `firefox`, but I wanted a generic answer which would be applicable to any process

Comment: Replace the string `firefox` in the wrapper script with a parameter substitution and pass the name of the command as an argument to the script.